# Is it possible to downgrade or upgrade a membership created on CiviCRM?

Tags: civimember

Is it possible to downgrade or upgrade a CiviMember membership? 
(upgrade = more access, more expensive / downgrade = less access, less expensive / both options need to be able to change joomla user group)
If yes, how? I can only find information about renewing the current membership.

Comment: Do you mean for an Admin to do this to a contact, or for a contact to do this, and do you mean at the time of renewing (where they should be able to change membership type on the contribution page) or part way through a year?

Comment: It would be great if the contact could do it at any time. We offer different levels of access on our website so if the contact decides to have access to more articles or products, it should be able to do it. Payments will be processed offline, so if contact decides to upgrade the membership it should be automatically approved and grant new level of access.

Comment: I've found discussions on this subject here from 2010:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/CiviMember+-+Phase+2+Specifications

However, I can't find anything to suggest that it actually made it into CiviMember.